# Firebase Authentication in Nextjs with Server Components

Tags: javascript, next.js, firebase-authentication, next.js13, react-server-components

I am trying to learn how to implement authentication with firebase to my nextjs app. First thing we do while using firebase is initialize our firebase with our configuration (`apiKey` etc.). If i use any firebase function from a client component, it requires this configuration to be sent to client and i think this is something we should never do?

https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-nextjs#5
But in this tutorial of google they do just that? They prefixed `.env` variables with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` which makes them available to client components? Would a company like google create a wrong tutorial for their product? Is it okay to send my firebase conf. to client?

If not how can i implement this functionality with server components. I think for sign in and sign out, I can call server actions?

The thing I cant do is how to listen for authentication state and render UI according to that(change sign in button to signout button etc.)

lets assume i have server component navbar:

```
function Navbar() {
  let signedIn = false;
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
    if (authUser) {
    signedIn = true;
    } 
  });
return (
 signedIn ? <SignOutButton /> : <SignInButton />
 )
}
```

I cant use state or useEffect on server component and i dont know declaring normal variable like this would be appropriate?

Comment: "If i use any firebase function from a client component, it requires this configuration to be sent to client and i think this is something we should never do?" See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please go through below

this is how a typical config. file looks like

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  authDomain: 'YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN',
  projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID',
  storageBucket: 'YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET',
  messagingSenderId: 'YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID',
  appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

you must be worrie about mostely by exposing the API key to public.so read below for that

( ref. [api-keys#general-info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#general-info))

> **API keys for Firebase are different from typical API keys**
>
> Unlike how API keys are typically used, API keys for Firebase services
> are not used to control access to backend resources; that can only be
> done with Firebase Security Rules (to control which users can access
> resources) and App Check (to control which apps can access resources).
>
> Usually, you need to fastidiously guard API keys (for example, by
> using a vault service or setting the keys as environment variables);
> however, API keys for Firebase services are ok to include in code or
> checked-in config files.
>
> Although API keys for Firebase services are safe to include in code,
> there are a few specific cases when you should enforce limits for your
> API key; for example, if you're using Firebase ML, Firebase
> Authentication with the email/password sign-in method, or a billable
> Google Cloud API. Learn more about these cases later on this page.

also go through [is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public)

if you are clear about the uses and working of the API keys in your firebase projest then you can follow the rest of implitation as usual

for example :

**for signInWithGoogle:**

```
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
};
```

now for the purpose of making sure user's authentication status(as you highlighted). You can use Subscribe states to authentication changes
To subscribe to authentication changes, follow these steps:

Navigate to the src/components/Header.jsx file.
Replace the useUserSession function with the following code:

```
function useUserSession(initialUser) {
        // The initialUser comes from the server through a server component
        const [user, setUser] = useState(initialUser);
        const router = useRouter();

        useEffect(() => {
                const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
                        setUser(authUser);
                });
                return () => {
                        unsubscribe();
                };
        }, []);

        useEffect(() => {
                onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
                        if (user === undefined) return;
                        if (user?.email !== authUser?.email) {
                                router.refresh();
                        }
                });
        }, [user]);

        return user;
}
```

for more details visit ref : [firebase-nextjs#5](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-nextjs#5)

Comment: thanks, thats a big relief. Google's Gemini still highly disagrees about sending firebase apikey to client though. for now, I will go for client components

Comment: yes sure , it is always best to follow strong security rules for any situation what so ever also because they are very flexible so you can always find best for your situation .